# readAxt() converts lowercase to uppercase

Tags: r, bioconductor

Is there any method where I can read AXT files without converting the sequences to uppercase automatically?

The link to the code is: https://github.com/alexander-nash/kurtosis_conservation/blob/master/get_identical_seq_locations.R

getLengthsOfIdenticalSeqs() this function compares two sequences and determines the lengths of the matched sequences. 
For example:
ATCGCGAT
TTCGAAAT
Output:
TCG of length 3
AT of length 3

But the problem is with the readAxt() function that automatically converts lowercase to uppercase and then compares sequences that are wrong.

```
if(species2 != "lepOcu1"){
  axts<-lapply(species2, function(x) {
    lel<-dir(paste0("Human-mouse/Human Mouse 2009/axtNet/"), pattern=paste0("chrX", ".*.axt"), full.names=T)
    lel<-lel[!grepl("Exon", lel)]
    lel<-lel[!grepl("broken", lel)]
    tfn<-paste0("Human-mouse/Human Mouse 2009/bigZips/hg19/", species1, ".2bit")
    if(!file.exists(tfn)) tfn<-paste0("Human-mouse/Human Mouse 2009/bigZips/hg19", species1, "/bigZips/", species1, ".2bit")
    qfn<-paste0("Human-mouse/Human Mouse 2009/bigZips/mm10/", species2, ".2bit")
    if(!file.exists(qfn)) qfn<-paste0("Human-mouse/Human Mouse 2009/bigZips/mm10", species2, "/bigZips/", species2, ".2bit")
    out<-readAxt(lel, tAssemblyFn=NULL, qAssemblyFn=NULL)
  })
}

names(axts)<-species2
print((axts))
```

This code outputs the following sequences:
A Axt with 80740 alignment pairs:
1 chrX     70345     70614  chr8  35873813  35874094 - 6175 
GGTACTGAGGTCCCCTGGGTACTGAGATCTCCTCGGTACTGAAGTCTCCTCGGTGCTGAGGTCGCCTCGGTGCTG...GGTACTGAGGTCGCCTAGGTACTGAGACCTTCTAGGTCCTGAGGT--------CTAGGTACTGAGG-CCTTCTCC
GATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTG...GATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCC

But the original sequence is (there exists lowercases):
0 chrX 70345 70614 chr8 35873813 35874094 - 6175

ggtacTGAGGTCCCCTGGGTACTGAGATCTCCTCGGTACTGAAGTCTCCTCGGTGCTGAGGTCGCCTCGGTGCTGAGACCTCCTAGGTATTGAGGTCGCCTCGGTACTGAGGTTGCCTC----------------------------GGTGCTGAGGT-----CGCCACGGTGCTGAGACCTCCTAGATACTGAGG----TCTCCTAGGCACGGAGATCTCCTATGTACAGAGACCTCGTCGGTACTGAGGTCGCCTAGGTACTGAGACCTTCTAGGTCCTGAGGT--------CTAGGTACTGAGG-CCTTCTCC

GATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTT-CCTCTCCCGGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCCCGGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCCCAG---------------------------------GATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCCCAGGATGCTGAGGTTCCTCTCC

Comment: Please give a short code example with output and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `DNAStringSet()` of `getLengthsOfIdenticalSeqs()` is to blame. And its not a bug its intended.

> Details:
> The DNAString class is a direct XString subclass (with no
> additional slot).  Therefore all functions and methods described
> in the XString man page also work with a DNAString object
> (inheritance).
> Unlike the BString container that allows storage of any single
> string (based on a single-byte character set) the DNAString
> container can only store a string based on the DNA alphabet (see
> below).  In addition, the letters stored in a DNAString object are
> encoded in a way that optimizes fast search algorithms.

You can either change the function in *get_identical_seq_locations.R* to use `readBStringSet()` or try to covert the strings back after printout.

For the latter it would be important to get sequence position information from the output.
You could first save the positions of the lower case bases and then put them back after printout, e.g.

```
DNA <- c("ACGTggTTAa")
lower <- sapply( strsplit( DNA, ""), function(x) grepl("[[:lower:]]",x) )
lower
       [,1]
 [1,] FALSE
 [2,] FALSE
 [3,] FALSE
 [4,] FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE
 [6,]  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE
 [8,] FALSE
 [9,] FALSE
[10,]  TRUE

DNA_out
[1] "ACGTGGTTAA"

DNA_out_split <- unlist(strsplit( DNA_out, "" ))

DNA_out_split[lower] <- tolower( DNA_out_split[lower] )

DNA_out <- paste(DNA_out_split, collapse="")
DNA_out
[1] "ACGTggTTAa"
```

I just don't know if there's a way to know the base positions after print out.